# mysql char length for utf8_swedish_ci

Tags: mysql, sql, character-encoding

I created a table with this field:

```
chr CHAR(1)
```

The charset and collate are:
    DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_swedish_ci

Well, even thought the field only can contain one single character, if I insert a value like:

```
insert into tbl values ('ö');
```

then the length of the field will return more than 1. Thus, the sql:

```
select length(chr) from tbl where id = 1
```

return 2. Why? Im aware that the charset/collation thing can be a real pain. I didnt have utf8_swedish_ci from the beginning, which wasnt good as I could not sort alphabetically (the ö was fetched after o which is wrong as the character ö is the last one in the alphabet).
So I guess it would be best for me to continue using utf8_swedish_ci. But then this bad thing happens. Anyone knows how to solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MySQL `length` function returns the length in bytes; you need `char_length` to get the number of characters.